# RPM sensor signal level shifting

Tags: stm32, sensor, level-shifting

I have an RPM sensor that outputs a square wave. The voltage level of the output signal varies between 3.3V and 8.4V depending on which supply voltage the user has chosen for the sensor.

I need a simple circuit that will always shift this voltage level to 3.3V to keep it safe for the STM32.

I found these three circuits.  One uses a 3.3V Zener while the other two use a 2N7002 MOSFET.

Which one is better and what are your thoughts?

I don't want to have signal inversion and i would like to have as low part count as possible due to limited pcb space.

If there is a ready Chip that can do this then it will bee perfect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: First thoughts from a newbie : -1- the zener based will always produces less than 3.3V depending on the current flowing through the zener but will probably always be enough for what you need. Zeners have a recovery time that you might take into account.  -2- the mosfet solution reverses the signal and is more expensive in most cases but I would go for that one.

Comment: Please mention how much current can be drawn from the sensor output? Also, are there any speed requirements like rise-time, fall-time and propagation delay for the level shifter

Comment: Hello sai, I don't know that information, but i can tell the following: i am using the Hobbywing rpm sensor (https://www.hobbywingdirect.com/products/rpm-sensor?variant=219217336) this sensor will output a signal of the same level of the supplied voltage so when we supply it with a voltage higher than 3.3V the output signal will have also higher level up to 8.4V, i need a circuits that will reduce that level back to 3.3V no matter which input it is receiving, you can consider that the input signal level to the circuit will be between 3.3V and 8.4V and the output should always be 3.3V.

Comment: From the link you provided, I was not able to get the info I was looking for. Can you tell me the max frequency of this square wave? Will your application work if there is say a few us delay from output of the sensor to the micro-controller added because of the level shifter? Is power consumption in the level shifter a concern?

Comment: max frequency will be around 12KHz I think, i don't want any delay because this affect the governor function in the mcu, the mcu circuit has a 500mA power supply and the circuit consumption is around 250mA

Comment: @AhmadKASSEM - Hi, (a) You posted an *answer*, but it was a further *question*. Therefore posting that as an answer is not allowed, as Q and A are in different places on Stack Exchange. In this case, another user added it into the question as an update for you. (b) Please see the [tour] & [help] for more site rules and to see how Stack Exchange is different from forums. (c) Although you are allowed to use an edit to the question to *clarify* it, be careful not to change or extend the question in a way that invalidates answers you already received to the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The third circuit you proposed will work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRO3XY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's a plot of simulated input (SENSOR, blue) and output (MCU orange) signals, in which you can see the MCU signal is capped at +3.3V, and is not inverted:

[image]

You only need a pull-up resistor at the input (R32 in your own schematic) if the output from your RPM sensor has an open drain/collector. If so, include R2 here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flJmwM.png)</sup>

Comment: The only other point I would check before selecting the pullup resistor values is to make sure that the pulldown in the RPM sensor is strong enough to sink the current coming from the pullups so that it does not violate the VIL of the MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Using the MOSFET based approach is a safer approach because the output high level will be exactly the supply voltage and the fact that it's delay will be lesser than the zener solution. When input is high, there will be 330uA current flowing through R14. If you want to avoid that, use a PMOS in it's place. R18 will draw 84uA when input is 8.4V. Is this ok? You can increase it further if current consumption is critical. The purpose of R18 is basically to define gate of the NMOS to 0V when the supply to the RPM sensor is not present.

Comment: the signal inversion caused by the MOSFET is a problem, can you propose another approach, other than the Zener? Will an opto-isolator do the job?

Comment: Use 2 inverters if the signal inversion is a concern. I was thinking that since you are anyway using an STM32, you can take care of the inversion inside your code.

Comment: I cannot alter the stm32 code, and i want to have as low part count as possible because the area on the PCB is very crowded.

Comment: @AhmadKASSEM, you could search for level shifter ICs on digikey that meet your space requirements.

Comment: I searched, but did not fine that can supports 8.4v input, can you propose one?

Comment: Please add all these requirements to the question. The space requirement and non-inversion requirements are not there in your original question